# How to declare a public variable for a specified user login?

Tags: vb.net

I have a login system that works well, using XML files to store logins, and then I can read the users and passwords, see if it matches, if it does, move to the next form, if it doesn't, error message.

However, when the form switches over, I want to be able to display the username in the to left corner, so the user knows who they are displayed as. But I don't know how to memorise the specific user that logged in on the previous form onto the new form now?

I tried making a "public variable" (sort of hard to do for me, not sure if i even did it right), which will read the textbok that the user inputs their name in if the username was correct, and gets dipaslayed for the next form. I don't thin the public vairable worked very well.

```
If BlnUserFound = True Then
    'ActiveUser is the "public vairable"
    ActiveUser = tbxUser.Text
    'Open the main screen
    Me.Hide()
    Home.Show()       
Else
    MessageBox.Show("User Details Not found" & vbCrLf _
                    & "Please Try Again", "Login Error")
End If
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: just call the tbxUser.Text from Form, where it is.. if you are for ex. in form2 you can call form1.tbxUser.Text from there

Answer (score 0):

Just simply connect it to another new variable name and use it in form 2 e.g
`dim ActiveUser2 as string
ActiveUser2 = Form1.ActiveUser` then just simply easiest way would be have a label or something on your form, set it to not visible and then just apply `ActiveUser2.text` to the `Label.Text`